# Convert a TypeMirror PrimitiveType to its Non Primitive Counterpart

Tags: java, annotations

I am writing an Annotation processor, and for some reason I need to convert the

`javax.lang.model.type.PrimitiveType` to a `DeclaredType`

is there another way then to do this then just switching through all possible primitive types?

Answer (score 0):

turns out that it is possible to use `Types` to box the type:

```
Types typeUtils = processingEnv.getTypeUtils();
typeUtils.boxedClass(primitiveType)
```